# CI CD .net core app on linux without Azure devops

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

Is there a way to publish and deploy a .NET CORE web application automatically without using azure devops ? I just don't want to pay Azure devops to use a single pipeline once every two months. I don't use Docker, I have a simple application that I'd like to publish and deploy on my Linux server automatically, every time I change it in Github.

Comment: You can use for that purpose any CI/CD pipelines mechanism (github actions, gitlab ci/cd, Jenkins, azure devops, circle ci and many more) In the CI script you want to create artifact of the application using "dotnet publish" command, then in your CD you want copy this artifact to your Linux server, extract it and execute main exeudable - everything using CI/CD scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use github actions to deploy on a linux instance, Microsoft has a guide for setting it up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/devops/create-dotnet-github-action

It's free to use, if using a public repo and it's free to start if it's a private repo

Comment: Azure Devops is free to use with a public repo too, I'm looking for a 100% free solution with private repos :)

Comment: Circle Ci offers 6000 minutes a month and github actions 2000 minutes, for private repos. As far as i know there isn't a completely free solution for private repos. But i do hope you find something :-)